# Is it possible to specify minimum and maximum weight values in encog?

Tags: java, encog

I tried to specify the minimum and maximum weight constraints of a BasicNetwork, but I simply can't find a way to do it. Is it possible to set these constraints?

Comment: It may help if you include a code snippet of how you are currently using that `BasicNetwork`.

Comment: @E_net4 I use this way: http://www.heatonresearch.com/wiki/Hello_World

Comment: Update your question, making it self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, the following code clamps the weights to between -10 and +10.  You could place this right into the HelloWorldXOR example.  The flat.getWeights is just a 1D array of the weights, so you can modify them as you wish.

```
    VectorAlgebra va = new VectorAlgebra();
    FlatNetwork flat = network.getFlat();
    do {
        train.iteration();
        va.clampComponents(flat.getWeights(), 5);
        System.out.println("Epoch #" + epoch + " Error:" + train.getError());
        epoch++;
    } while(train.getError() > 0.01);
```